# Moving Piwik to another hosting, database error #1044

Tags: mysql

I just moved to another hosting and while I'm trying to import piwik database, I got this error:

```
    SQL query:


-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.8.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Serveur: custsql-ipg49.eigbox.net
-- Généré le : Mardi 20 Septembre 2016 à 05:38
-- Version du serveur: 5.6.32
-- Version de PHP: 4.4.9
-- 
-- Base de données: `piwik`
-- 
CREATE DATABASE `piwik` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'xyz'@'localhost' to database 'piwik'
```

Comment: Then with what user did you log in to mysql? Or how are you executing this line?

Comment: What line?, I just imported it via phpmyadmin  and my database server said: user: MyHostingUserName@localhost

Comment: You probably already have a specified database which you can only use. Which is what a lot of hosting companies do.

Answer (score 0):

Your user 'xyz' doesn't have proper permissions on the 'piwik' database. You have to either use another user account, give that user the proper permissions, or use a database for which you do have access.

Many hosting companies only give you access to one database, that could be the case here, or it could simply be that the user you're using hasn't been granted the proper permissions. If you have administrative access to the MySQL instance, you can change permissions, otherwise you'll have to work around it. One thing you could do is export the database so that it uses the name that your host allows you to use, from phpMyAdmin's export page there's an option for "Rename exported databases/tables/columns" (you can also manually edit your .sql file to accomplish this). Then when you import in to your new host, it will use that database name and table names instead. Then you just have to configure piwik to use the new database name and table prefix instead.